# Introduce z-index as a variable within xml data for atributes relating to markers

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3, z-index

I have a large number of markers in same area, and I would like to eb able to bring a couple to the front. By default Google api v3 is stacking z-index my which one has a lower latitude I believe. I know this can be over riden, but having a little trouble adjusting my code syntax to allow this. Here is what I have tried:

```js
var select_html = ""; 

  // arrays to hold copies of the markers
  // because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
  var gmarkers = []; 

 // global "map" variable
  var map = null;

  var gicons=[];
gicons['yellow'] ="http://www.ghd.com/canada/ghd_grey.png";
gicons["grey"] = "http://www.ghd.com/canada/ghd2.png";



var image = {
url: 'ghd.png',
// This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
size: new google.maps.Size(59, 70),
// The origin for this image is 0,0.
origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
// The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 70)
};
var shadow = {
url: 'images/beachflag_shadow.png',
// The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
// while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
size: new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
};
// Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
// The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
// traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
// coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
// coordinate.
var shape = {
  coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
  type: 'poly'
 };



// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html, icontype, zIndex) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    icon : gicons[icontype],
     shadow: shadow,
     optimized: false,
    zIndex: 10 
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    // ======= Add the entry to the select box =====
    select_html += '<option> ' + name + '<\/option>';
    // ==========================================================
// save the info we need to use later
gmarkers.push(marker);
return marker;
}

  // ======= This function handles selections from the select box ====
  // === If the dummy entry is selected, the info window is closed ==
  function handleSelected(opt) {
    var i = opt.selectedIndex - 1; 
    if (i > -1) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
    }
    else {
      infowindow.close();
    }
  }

function initialize() {
// create the map
var myOptions = {
zoom: 2,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.8624,-96.654218),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                            myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });

  // Read the data from 100.xml
  downloadUrl("canada_offices.xml", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    // ==== first part of the select box ===
    select_html = '<p>For Guam and Saipan offices, please see drop down  
   list</p>'+'<select onChange="handleSelected(this)">' +
                    '<option selected> - Select a location - <\/option>';
    // =====================================

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
      var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
        var icontype = markers[i].getAttribute("icontype");
         var zIndex = markers[i].getAttribute("zIndex");

      // create the marker
      var marker = createMarker(point,label,html,icontype,zIndex);
    }
    // ===== final part of the select box =====
    select_html += '<\/select>';
    document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = select_html;
  });
  }

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
 { 
 size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
});


// This Javascript is based on code provided by the
// Community Church Javascript Team
// http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/
// from the v2 tutorial page at:
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic3.htm 
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zIndex on markers is only effective if you set it on all of them.

To emulate the "default" google behavior,  I use this (from Mike Williams in the v2 API):

```
zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
```

To pop one of these markers above the markers in that area add an offset to that marker.

[Example using zIndex](http://www.geocodezip.com//v3_MW_example_map15c.html)

createMarker looks like this:

```js
// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html, icontype, zIndex) {
  var contentString = html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    icon : gicons[icontype],
    shadow: shadow,
    optimized: false,
    zIndex: zIndex+Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

  // ======= Add the entry to the select box =====
  select_html += '<option> ' + name + '<\/option>';
  // ==========================================================
  // save the info we need to use later
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  return marker;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now do you add an offset to that marker to pop it above markers. I assumed the approach would be defining z-index as a variable in html to be passed to each marker via xml, than assigning a value for z-index for each marker with ones you want at top having a higher number? (much how it works in css).

Comment: Modified the createMarker function to add a fourth parameter "zIndex" that is added to the computed value to allow the markers to be adjusted.  You could parse that out of your xml and pass it to the createMarker function.

Comment: @user2786507, as geocodezip could tell elsewhere, if the answer helps you, and is correct - then mark it as accepted. You havent accepted any answer yet. Accepting will help to 1) know the question is answered 2) help people with similar problems 3) you earn yourself a shiny badge

Comment: Hi Geocodezip, thanks. I tried to implement, but as following shows, the stacking still does not seem to have kicked in as [example](http://www.dmansdesign.com/maps_new/canada.html) shows

Comment: Do you want to dynamically change the zIndex when the entry is selected in the select box?  Or is it static, you want one or two always on top?

Comment: I want three on top, the blue flags (coded icontype grey in xml just to make things confusing, they are the first three entries) I want on the top all the time. So static.

Comment: Actually, i have worked it out. I assigned a z-index only to the markers I wanted to show at top and none of the others, and they are now displaying at top. Thanks.